# Is there a required spacing between where high and low voltage lines attach to a house?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

If both the high and low voltage lines are strung from the pole to the house, is there a minimum spacing required between where they anchor to the structure?

The AC lines enter through the weatherhead, and the CATV lines are attached to the house. Does the CATV (or phone) lines have to be a minimum distance away from the weatherhead?

Comment: are you talking about 120/240 vac and cable tv?

Comment: @shirlockhomes I am, CATV or telephone.

Comment: This was common in the area where I grew up (mostly late 1950s construction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are slight differences depending on what type of communications systems we're talking about, we'll have to look at a few different sections.

## NEC 2008

### Article 800 Communications Circuits

> **800.44 Overhead Communications Wires and Cables.**
> **(A) On Poles and In-Span.**
> **(4) Clearance.** Supply service drops of 0–750 volts running above and parallel to communications service drops shall have a minimum
> separation of 300 mm (12 in.) at any point in the span, including the
> point of and at their attachment to the building, provided the
> non-grounded conductors are insulated and that a clearance of not less
> than 1.0 m (40 in.) is maintained between the two services at the
> pole.

### Article 810 Radio and Television Equipment

> **810.13 Avoidance of Contacts with Conductors of Other Systems.** Outdoor antennas and lead-in conductors from an antenna to a building
> shall not cross over open conductors of electric light or power
> circuits and shall be kept well away from all such circuits so as to
> avoid the possibility of accidental contact. Where proximity to open
> electric light or power service conductors of less than 250 volts
> between conductors cannot be avoided, the installation shall be such
> as to provide a clearance of at least 600 mm (2 ft). Where
> practicable, antenna conductors shall be installed so as not to cross
> under open electric light or power conductors.

### Article 820 Community Antenna Television and Radio Distribution

> **820.44 Overhead Coaxial Cables.**
> **(B) Lead-in Clearance.** Lead-in or aerial-drop coaxial cables from a pole or other support, including the point of initial attachment to
> a building or structure, shall be kept away from electric light,
> power, Class 1, or non–power limited fire alarm circuit conductors so
> as to avoid the possibility of accidental contact.
>
> ***Exception:** Where proximity to electric light, power, Class 1, or non–power-limited fire alarm circuit service conductors cannot be
> avoided, the installation shall be such as to provide clearances of
> not less than 300 mm (12 in.) from light, power, Class 1, or
> non–power-limited fire alarm circuit service drops. The clearance
> requirement shall apply at all points along the drop, and it shall
> increase to 1.02 m (40 in.) at the pole.*

## Article 830 Network-Powered Broadband Communications Systems

> **830.44 Aerial Cables.**
> **(C) Lead-in Clearance.** Lead-in or aerial-drop network-powered broadband communications cables from a pole or other support,
> including the point of initial attachment to a building or structure,
> shall be kept away from electric light, power, Class 1, or
> non–power-limited fire alarm circuit conductors so as to avoid the
> possibility of accidental contact.
>
> ***Exception:** Where proximity to electric light, power, Class 1, or non–power-limited fire alarm circuit service conductors cannot be
> avoided, the installation shall be such as to provide clearances of
> not less than 300 mm (12 in.) from light, power, Class 1, or
> non–power-limited fire alarm circuit service drops. The clearance
> requirement shall apply to all points along the drop, and it shall
> increase to 1.02 m (40 in.) at the pole.*

---

## tl;dr.

### Telephone (Communication Systems)

- 12" (300 mm) at any point of the span.
- 12" (300 mm) at the point of attachment.
- 40" (1 m) at the service pole.

### Antenna (Radio and Television Equipment)

- Kept away if possible.
- Should not cross over or under.
- 2' (600 mm) if proximity can't be avoided.

### Cable (Community Antenna Television and Radio Distribution)

- Kept away if possible.
- 12" (300 mm) if proximity can't be avoided.
- 40" (1.02 m) at the service pole.

### Broadband (Network-Powered Broadband Communications Systems)

- Kept away if possible.
- 12" (300 mm) if proximity can't be avoided.
- 40" (1.02 m) at the service pole.